# In logics , there exists for atleast two or more elements?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Lets say, I have a set $S= \{2,3,5,6,7\}$.  I am having a logic query, if atleast $2$ elements greater $5$ is found in this set, then It should return true.  $\exists x: (x>5)$. This  formula works even if  $S= \{2,3,5,6 \}$ but I want a formula works only if $2$ or more elements greater than $5$ is found.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Try $$\exists x.\ x > 5 \land \exists y.\ y > x,$$
please note that the left quantifier extends its scope to the end of formula, i.e.

$$\exists x.\ \bigg((x > 5) \land \Big(\exists y.\ (y > x)\Big)\bigg).$$

Try to construct analogous expression for 3 elements $\ddot\smile$

Comment: It will by more convenient and readable if $\exists y$ is moved outside to same level as $\exists x$

Comment: @Trismegistos I wrote it that way for the benefit of Matt (however, he removed his formula).

Comment: @dtldarek Sorry, I didn't want to leave wrong things lying around. I appreciate it though!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify that a pair of objects should exist, e.g. $\exists\:(x,y) :(x>5\wedge y>5 \wedge x\ne y$).

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I prefer the first one. My logic language doesnt support conjunction.

Comment: In what language is the first well-formed? -- unless the comma is just a notational variant for $\land$?

Comment: Also, in the second formula, the right appearance of $x$ is free (the scope of quantifier of left $x$ ends with the parenthesis). And you miss one closing parenthesis too.

Comment: Hmm - the problem here is that I'm not a logician (although I can at least answer that the comma is indeed a substitute for $\wedge$). This is my own fault for not reading the tags; I'd read this as more of a programming question, so my answer should be read as a sort of pseudocode. If the second statement is completely wrong, I can just delete it (rather than worrying about how to fix the parentheses). If the first statement is also wrong then the entire answer should probably go.

Comment: Well, I would say this is a good opportunity for you to learn ;-) Could you imagine, why a compiler would complain about the right $x$ begin undefined?

Comment: @dtldarek Indeed! And I think I see the point - when trying to evaluate the expression, you'd want to evaluate each side and then compare, rather than reading left to right, and the right-hand one doesn't make sense on it's own. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @MattPressland Almost, you have separated the two subexpressions yourself, by enclosing the left one in additional pair of parentheses, hence, the $x$ from the left quantifier was not "available" in the right subexpression.

Comment: @dtldarek Sure, I meant that as I had written it, the two sides would evaluate before the binary operation $\wedge$ in the middle. Which is ultimately an entirely standard thing about brackets, that I should have noticed in the first place!